# Apply scenario on inline edit in table

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop, foundry-scenarios

Is it possible to apply to a scenario an inline edit action on a table widget?
I don't see the "Apply to scenario" toggle like in the button widget configuration.
[image]

Note: My table widget is based on a scenario.

Answer (score 1):

So actually if you turn on the 'Load Data From Scenarios' toggle, and set the variable to your active scenario, any inline edits will be written to the scenario not the write-back.